# Create plist file via code

Tags: objective-c, arrays, plist, nsdictionary

I want to create a plist file like this:

[image: Not made with code.]

in code, and then it will be in the Caches folder. 
I already know how to fetch the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
//Create a Mutant Dictionary
NSMutableDictionary *theMutantDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

//Fill it with data
[theMutantDict setObject:@"John" forKey:@"Name"];
[theMutantDict setObject:@"Doe" forKey:@"Lastname"];

//Then search for cache dir 
NSString *libraryDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, 
                  NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *cacheDir = [libraryDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Caches"];

//Then write the file
NSString *filePath = [cacheDir stringByAppendingString:@"/TheFile.plist"];
[theMutantDict writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: by the way, if you want to put more nested data like in the picture, you can use setObject method to put an array or other dictionary inside the mutant dictionary. Regards

Comment: Works! but say I have a textfield and a button. When I push the button the textfields value are stored written to file. But then you change the value in the textfield and push the button again. How do I do so it's not being replaced in the plist, added instead?

Comment: In that case, you have to change the "key" string that you use in setObject, every time you push the button. If it works, please give me an up!.

Comment: I will make your answer accepted if you can tell me how I could change it every time a new value is inserted and if its an value already there not add it? Thanks for helping!

Comment: Ok, here is the thing, when you set an object in a dictionary you insert the object with a "key". Think in the key like a number of a page in a book. If you insert a page with the same number (key) you replace the page. If you want to add another object to the dictionary, you have to do it with another key. So, you every time you push the button you can do: i++; NSString *theKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key%d",i];, where "i" should be an integer previously declared, like (int i = 0). Then, use "theKey" as key:[theMutantDict setObject:@"whatever" forKey:theKey]; .

Answer (score 3):

Just use the writeToFile-method of NSArray to store the array in a plist and arrayWithContentsOfFile to load it.

```
[self.array writeToFile:path atomically:YES];

self.array = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path];

// or in case you need to add/remove objects (NSMutableArray):
self.array = [[[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:path] mutableCopy] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 1):

If you got your data stored in an NSArray it's as easy as this:

```
// filling array with data ...

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *plistPath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my_nsarray_data.plist"];
[klasserArray writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];

// other stuff ...
```