# Writing new keys to a .plist file based on textField

Tags: ios

What I want to do is to populate a pickerView from an array based on a .plist, which can be added to from a textField. I've got it to work, but it only adds one key and replaces it when a new one is added. For instance if I add "hello", and then try to add another one, it replaces hello with something else.

```
- (IBAction)setContext:(id)sender {

NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];

NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"fullArray" ofType:@"plist"];
NSString *textFieldText = textField.text;

NSMutableDictionary *rootDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
[rootDict setValue:textField.text forKey:textField.text];

NSString *writablePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fullArray.plist"];
[rootDict writeToFile:writablePath atomically: YES];

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); //1

NSString *plistPath = [documentsDirectory     stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"fullArray.plist"]; //3

NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSArray *array = [dictionary allKeys];

arrayContext = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:array];

[pickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

[textField endEditing:YES];

[pickerView reloadAllComponents];

}
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you are creating a new NSMutableDictionary every time you pick something in the picker, the correct approach is:

1. Create a NSMutableDictionary as a property.
2. Every time you pick, create a new string for the key, maybe using [NSString stringWithFormat:].
3. use [mutableDictionary setObject:forKey] for set a new object in the mutant dictionary, with the new created key.

Comment: Here I answer a similar question, with code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9673140/create-plist-file-via-code/9673615#9673615

Comment: No, what I'm trying to do is have a textField at the top with a button to add the textField.text into the array and write it to the .plist.